Fourm software on the Fediverse (ActivityPub Federated Forums)
Are there any software for self-hosting a forum website that uses ActivityPub?
I'm looking for a UX similar to popular forum software, such as:

Discourse
Flarum
Xenforo
phpBB
etc

...except that I want people all over the fediverse to be able to post in the forum's threads (for example, from their account on a Mastodon instance)
Is there any Internet Forum software that federates with ActivityPub?

NodeBB looks to be the only forum software with any sort of reasonable support. It claims to have two-way support, so that includes posting from other places. It's still being worked on and available only in 4.0 prereleases, though.

You can use lemmy and or its fork sublinks.
Though originally designed as an alternative to reddit, you can swap the UI to something like lemmyBB, which gives a very similar UX to phpBB








Screenshot of lemmyBB showing two forums (communities)



